# Any way to close popup by button clicking in qml?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want a button to show/hide popup,like below:

```
    Button{
        id:btn

        text:"open"
        onClicked: {
            if(pup.opened)
            {
                pup.close()
            }
            else
            {
                pup.open()
            }
        }
    }

    Popup {
        id: pup
        x: 100
        y: 100
        width: 200
        height: 300
    }
```

Open the popup is ok.
But,when mouse above the button and be clicked, the popup is closed by effects of default `closePolicy` first.
And then `onClicked` of button is emitted,so the popup is opened again.
I want it looks like the popup is closed by button clicked(I want keep default closePolicy also).
Has any advise?

**Qt version:5.15.2**

Comment: Not the cleanest solution, but you can check for a boolean value that shows whether the popup is open or not. If it is open, you close it, if it is not, you open it. Rather than opening it on each click.

Comment: So what you would do, is to call a function (lets call it `popup.lets_see_whether_to_open_or_close()`) inside the `onClicked`. In the initialization of the button, you define a bool variables `is_popup_open` and initialize it to `false`. Then, every time the function above is called, you alter between the two states, and open or close accordingly.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you will have to keep track of the `is_popup_open` variable and update it, if popup is opened or closed by other means.

Answer (score 0):

> Open the popup is ok. But,when mouse above the button and be clicked,
> the popup is closed by effects of default closePolicy first. And then
> onClicked of button is emitted,so the popup is opened again. I want it
> looks like the popup is closed by button clicked(I want keep default
> closePolicy also). Has any advise?

It's impossible because the default policy value is **Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutside**. In your case, the "open" button is outside the popup area and that's why it breaks policy. You have two solutions:

**I. Change policy:**

```
Button{
    id:btn

    text:"open"
    z: 100

    onClicked: {
        if(pup.opened)
        {
            pup.close()
        }
        else
        {
            pup.open()
        }
    }
}

Popup {
    id: pup
    x: 100
    y: 100
    width: 200
    height: 300
    closePolicy: Popup.NoAutoClose
}
```

**II. Fake behaviour:**

Use the "open" button only to open the dialogue and close it by tapping outside the popup. You can disable the button when the popup is opened and it should fake the behaviour which you want. Additionally, you can customise the button and the style can be the same for enabled and disabled states.

```
Button{
    id:btn

    text:"open"
    z: 100
    enabled: !pup.opened

    onClicked: {
        if(pup.opened)
        {
            pup.close()
        }
        else
        {
            pup.open()
        }
    }
}

Popup {
    id: pup
    x: 100
    y: 100
    width: 200
    height: 300
}
```